# Binding DispatchTimer value In Windows 8 GridApp

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Is there a way to bind `DispatcherTimer` tick event  to one of  field in SampleDataItem in SampleDataSource.cs .

I want to show countdowntimer  where subtitle is how in default  SampleDataItme of groupedview page.

for example to calculate the time left for 12 DEC i am using and in subtitle field i am just putting function name, but it shows time left for 12 DEC on starting of application, after that it becomes static.

```
 public string CalculateTimeRemaining()
    {
        DateTime daysLeft = DateTime.Parse("12/12/2013 12:00:01 AM");
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

        //Calculate countdown timer.
        TimeSpan t = daysLeft - startDate;
        int Days = t.Days;
        int Hours = t.Hours;
        int totalH = Hours + (Days * 24); ;
        string countDown = totalH.ToString() + ":" + t.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + t.Seconds.ToString();
        return countDown;
    }
```

and in sampledataitem

```
 group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-3",
                "ABC",
                "CalculateTimeRemaining()",
                "Assets/3.png",
                "Item Description",
                ITEM_CONTENT,
                group1, ));
```

SampleDataSource.cs is default file in GridApp template of Windwos8 and sampledataitem is generated by template.

I tried

```
DispatchTimer myTimer = new DispatchTimer();

 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;
        myTimer.Start(); 
    }

private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {  var sampleDataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups("AllGroups");       
       groupetItemViewSource.Source = sampleDataGroups   //groupetItemViewSource is CollectionViewSource
     }
```

Is there a way show that it shows countdown per second and change value every second in GroupedItemView?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SampleDataItem` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and a `TimeRemaining` property that would be updated on `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event would raise the `PropertyChanged` event to update the binding.

Comment: As SampleDataItem already inherits INotifyPropertyChanged  from Bindablebase through SampleDataCommon, I added OnPropertyChanged in subtitle  set property. But in Timer_tick event loading individual property is not possibel I guess.
Though I solved problem by other way, It would be nice to know to solve it using binding.
Thanks for reply

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but if you have a bindable property (one that raises PropertyChanged event on change) and you change that property on tick events - the UI bound to the property will update.

Comment: What i meant to say was that subtitle property of SampleDataItem is not accessible in GroupedItems page to modify as such 
P.S. all reference are to grid app template generated by visual studio

Comment: I can't see how it would not be accessible to modify. If it's your code - you can modify it.